# Find words with all caps and replace with sentence case (Notepad++)

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

It should only match Latin characters. (I am happy for EmEditor suggestions too)

For example, for these strings:

```
ΜΕΓΑΛΗ μπίρα BOCK
ΜΕΓΑΛΗ μπίρα BOCK-BRANEL
ΜΕΓΑΛΗ μπίρα BOCK-BRANEL-CUMVAT
```

Should become:

```
ΜΕΓΑΛΗ μπίρα Bock
ΜΕΓΑΛΗ μπίρα Bock-Branel
ΜΕΓΑΛΗ μπίρα Bock-Branel-Cumvat
```

There should be a way to define the number of consecutive capitals a word would have for it to be changed to sentence case. For example from 4 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are your friend. I believe you want this:

Find what: `([A-Z])([A-Z]{3,})`

Replace with: `\1\L\2`

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly :)

Comment: `{1}` is superfluous.

Comment: @greektranslator Glad it worked. Please, accept the answer so people does not waste time in an already solved problem. @Toto, noted that. I was doing some tests and forgot about the `{1}`...